# Putting a wider tire on my bicycle

Tags: tire, size

Can I put a 24x3 inch tire on a rim that is normally for a 24x 2 1/4 inch tire

Comment: Before tagging this as duplicate of tire width question, please take a moment to remember that same inch diameter may be used for different rim diameters.

Comment: The general rule of thumb is that fractional and decimal inch sizes do not fit the same rim, but there are exceptions. The easiest solution is to look if there is an ETRTO size (a series of numbers that's something like 507-60 or similar). The first number is rim diameter in millimeters. If this matches, the limiting factor is if the wider tire fits inside forks. If the number is different, it will not fit.

Comment: How wide is your rim? In my experience it depends on the design of the tire (how wide the tire is where the tire beads are located. Could you provide info (and perhaps a link to) the specific tires (narrow and wide) and perhaps a photo if possible? In general you can put quite wide (balloon type tires) on relatively narrow rims without I'll effects (if you inflate the tires enough that is)